# Maven Dependency of type pom

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

Does maven allow to have a direct dependency of type pom? You can consider this pom to further have some library dependencies.

```
<project>
...
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>test-artifact</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

The packaging type of test-artifact is pom. So can we have above statement in Maven pom.xml without using scope import as adding scope import in dependencies is something that would not work.

Comment: Is this really relatex to Maven 2? A pom which contains dependencies in `dependencyManagement` is called a BOM which has to be done like this: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#importing-dependencies